# Scope inside the scope. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created directive for a page that adds some animations to the content. The html looks like this:

```
<div flip-animation>
  <span flip-animation-left>
    <img src="/images/viceralfat.png">
  </span>
  <figcaption flip-animation-right>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </figcaption>
</div>
```

so as you see inside the div there is `flip-animation` wich has two more childrend `flip-animation-left` and `flip-animation-right`so what I wonna do is to grab the `flip-animation`and check its child whether it is left or right. If it is right I have one function, but if its is left I have another function. My question is that How can I check if it is right or left

**EDIT**
here is my directive:

'use strict';

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('flipAnimation', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        // here I wonna check if its right or left
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function in the `controller` of the "parent" directive that will be consumed by its children directives. Then, inside the child directives use `require` in order to have access to the `controller` of the parent directive, so that the child directives can consume their parent's function.

Like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('flipAnimation',['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        controller: function(){
            this.flip = function(flipRight){
                if(flipRight){
                    //Code for Flip Right here
                }else{
                    //Code for Flip Left here
                }                
            }
        },
        link: function link(scope, elem, attrs) {}
    }
}])
.directive('flipAnimationpRigth',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        require: '^flipAnimation',         
        link: function link(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.flip(true);
        }
    }
})
.directive('flippAnimationLeft',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        require: '^flipAnimation',         
        link: function link(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.flip(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: dear @Josep, thanks for your respond. Your way is the solution, but I still have a misunderstanding. Now that the 'Left' and 'Right' are separated, how can I get access to the 'elem' of the 'Right' or 'Left'. What I mean by that "silly"question is that when I am inside the ````if(flipRight){}```` the ````elem````should give me ````<figcaption flip-animation-right>...</figcaption```` 

and when I am inside the 'Left' the ````elem```` should give me ````<span flip-animation-left>...</span>````

Comment: @Max the easiest way (maybe not the bets, though) would be to pass it as a parameter. In the 'flipAnimation' controller change the 'flip' function definition like this `this.flip = function(flipRight, childElem){...`, and then when you call the function from one of the child directives do this: `ctrl.flip(false, elem);`